# Simple unit test for Angular service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-services

I have an Angular service that receives a number `N` (between 1-12) and returns the sum of integers up to `12 - N`:

```
app.value('myNumberService', {
    calculateValue: function (n) {
        var empty = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 12 - n; i++){
            empty.push(i);
        }
        return empty;
    }
});
```

I am trying to write a very basic unit test to check that the service is defined:

```
describe('app', function () {

    var app, service;

    beforeEach(function () {
        app = angular.mock.module('app')
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        service = $injector.get('myNumberService');
    }));             

    describe('*Validating myNumberService service', function () {           
        describe("calculateValue", function(){
            it("should be defined.", function(){
                expect(service.calculateValue()).toBeDefined();
            });
        });
    });     
});
```

I receive this error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7) app *Validating myNumberService service encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'service.calculateValue')
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why your test is failing on first glance. However, it's got a lot of stuff that could be improved (and somewhere in the middle is probably the mistake). Here's how I'd write a unit test for that module:

```
describe('app', function () {

    var myNumberService;

    beforeEach(module(this.description));    // this.description === 'app'

    beforeEach(inject(function (_myNumberService_) {
        myNumberService = _myNumberService_;    // see documentation for `angular.mock.inject`
    }));

    describe('myNumberService', function () {

        it('calculates ...', function () {
            expect(myNumberService.calculateValue(...)).toBe(...);
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, I don't actually test service's presence there. This is because if the service doesn't exist, tests requiring its injection will fail with a quite understandable error. Your unit tests should explicitly test just the functionality of your unit; basic integrity of your code will be tested implicitly. To give another example, you wouldn't test that `calculateValue` is a function. (The first test that tries to use it as a function will fail with *"... is not a function"* anyway, if it's not.)

---

Bonus hint: Sum of `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` can be calculated [simply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) as `(n * (n + 1)) / 2`.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. Shame i had to give up 50 points for such a simple issue.